# Inserting data in 2 tables using the id of the 1st query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables `users` and `addresses`. The user enters all the data from one form, Then all data is inserted into the database.

The 2 tables structures look like that:

```
       `users`

+-------------------+
| id | name | email |
|--------------------
|  1 |  jon | j@j.co|
+-------------------+
    
          `addresses`

+-----------------------------+
| id | add1 | add2  | user_id |
|-----------------------------|
|  1 |  NY  | Vegas |    1    |
+-----------------------------+
```

As you see there is a relation between the 2 tables using `users.id` and `addresses.user_id`.

PHP code to insert data:

```
//Insert for 1st table
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $email]);

//Last inserted id
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

//Insert for 2nd table
$sql = "INSERT INTO addresses(add1, add2, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$add1, $add2, $id]);
```

With this scenario, Imagine there are 2 users filling the form at the same time. One with id `2` and the other with id `3`.

So the users table would be like that:

```
    +-------------------+
    | id | name | email |
    |--------------------
    |  1 |  jon | j@j.co|
    |--------------------
    |  2 | mark | m@m.co|
    |--------------------
    |  3 |  sam | s@s.co|
    +-------------------+
```

So when it reaches this line  `$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();`, The id would be `3` and if this happens, The user with id `3` would have 2 rows in `addresses` table, Right?

```
        `addresses`

+-----------------------------+
| id | add1 | add2  | user_id |
|-----------------------------|
|  1 |  NY  | Vegas |    1    |
|-----------------------------|
|  2 |  UK  |  UK   |    3    |
|-----------------------------|
|  3 |  CA  |  CA   |    3    |
+-----------------------------+
```

Is that's possible to happen that the last inserted id would be for a different user? Or MYSQL handles that?

If it's possible, Is there is a better and accurate way then?

Comment: No. It wont happen. Assuming both data are processed through a single file say insert_address.php. Your PDO instantiated for user 2 will have last id as only 2. 3 does not exist when user 2 is executing the code. Also, 2 & 3 requests does not access the file at the same time. Thats what the server handles.

Comment: Agreed with AlaksandarJesusGene. You don't need to code you application to account for this. Your server and RDBMS will handle this.

Comment: That's really great. I didn't know that server does that